# Samsung Galaxy Gio network menu

Tags: sim-unlocking, samsung-galaxy-gio

I have a problem with my galaxy gio. It has a network lock (I think) and I've tried to unlock it. The problem is that I have the unlock code but the phone doesn't ask for it. It is there a menu or a key code to open that menu to enter the unlock code or any other solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. The device has a custom rom and you cannot unblock them so. I had to flash the device with a stock one and Odin and then it asked me for network key.

Answer (score 0):

At least on older phones the unlock codes work directly from the dialing interface. Try to enter the code as if you were calling it (from the dialer).

Comment: I've already tried that ...

Comment: Another method is to boot the phone with a non-supported SIM card, and it should ask for the Network Lock Control Key, or you can try entering #7465625*638*unlockcode# into the dialer, or #0111*unlockcode#, or just #7465625*638*# and then the unlock code when it asks for it.

Comment: Yeah I've solved the problem. The device has a custom rom and you cannot unblock them so. I had to flash the device with a stock one and Odin and then it asked me for network key. Anyway thanks :)